# Why is HEAD ahead of master?

Tags: git

I have the HEAD and my origin/master synced, but my master is behind by two commits.
Calling git branch -a reveals that I am detached from 16e6202(master). **Can someone explain what this means?**

```
* e3acad6 (HEAD, origin/master) 14-delete task feature added
* 26641b1 13-edit task feature added
* 16e6202 (master) 12-full tasks example from beginning
```

How can I reconcile the HEAD again with master?

Comment: This is not a duplicate - i have no branch

Comment: Ah I see the subtle difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You checked out `origin/master`, so you have a *detached HEAD*, which means you are currently not on a local branch. You need to checkout `master` again to be *on* that branch again.

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master --ff-only
```

Comment: Thanks. this worked a charm for me. What is the difference between a remote repository and a branch? can you consider a repo a branch?

Comment: The remote branch (`origin/master`) is not really that different from a local branch. The only special thing about them is that they belong to a remote, and as such Git prevents you from *moving* them, making it essentially not work like a local branch (hence the “detached HEAD”). But for the rest, it’s really just the same mechanic: It’s a pointer to a commit in your repository.

Comment: @seasick, here is the chapter in the documentation that explains these branches http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: But doing this, will I lose my new code made on HEAD? Cause, that´s what my HEAD is, a bunch of new code that isn´t on MASTER

Comment: @MarcelloPatto If you committed on the detached HEAD and it is now ahead of both master and origin/master, then you can just update your master branch to HEAD using `git update-ref refs/heads/master HEAD`. That will simply reset the master branch to point on your current HEAD. Afterwards, check out master to continue there.